pascal's triangle code resulting in an infinite loop
title
i'm trying to program pascal's triangle in c# and i cant understand whats wrong with the code,
this is what i wrote:
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int numrows = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    PascalsTriangle(numrows);
}
static void PascalsTriangle(int numRows)
{
    List<int> triangle = new List<int>();
    List<int> trianglestorage = new List<int>();
    Console.WriteLine("   " + string.Join("", triangle));
    for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine();
        triangle.Add(1);
        triangle.Insert(0, 1);
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", triangle)); // this is the last normal output and the system shows memory overflow error inside the loop. for some reason it goes on forever even though triangle.Count is now 3 and it should repeat only twice 
        for (int j = 0; j < triangle.Count() - 1; j++)
        {
            trianglestorage.Add(triangle[j] + triangle[j+1]);
        }
        triangle = trianglestorage;
    }

}

currently the output is looking like this:
1
1, 1
1, 2, 1
then the program just keeps on going without outputting anything and eventually it closes due to memory overflow

triangle=trianglestorage is an assignment, not a copy. After it has been executed for the first time, both point to the same list. Now extrapolate from this info...

This might help: What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?.

Hint: your stop condition checks the length of a list that your loop body adds elemts to.  So it's basically "i<N?" and in the the next iteration "i<N+1?" and so on. It will never stop.

@Fildor well now it works
i dont know if its the most optimal way but i just cleared the list and used AddRange(trianglestorage)

For learning it doesn't matter so much if it's optimal. First make it work. More important would be that you investigate and understand why it didn't before.

Use the triangle.Count property which just returns the stored count instead of the triangle.Count() extension method which might loop through the list to determine its size. You actually get a smart tag telling you to Use Count property instead of Enumerable.Count method.

The code with some changes.
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace console_test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int numrows = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            PascalsTriangle(numrows);
        }

        static void PascalsTriangle(int numRows)
        {
            string[] lines = new string[numRows];
            string[] previous_lines = new string[numRows];
            for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++)
            {
                lines = new string[i + 1];
                lines[0] = "1"; lines[lines.Length - 1] = "1";
                for (int j = 0; j < i - 1; j++)
                {
                    lines[j + 1] = (int.Parse(previous_lines[j]) + int.Parse(previous_lines[j + 1])).ToString(); 
                }
                previous_lines = lines;
                Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", lines));
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}


Instead of just posting some code, it would be better to explain what and why you changed it.

Just used array string instead of list.
lines[1]= previous_lines[0]+previous_lines[1];
lines[2]= previous_lines[1]+previous_lines[2];
...
